# 0 division in a 'when else' environment

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have the following code:

```
CASE WHEN (1+sum(x)/sum(y)) >=0 and (1+sum(x)/sum(y)) < 0.5 Then 1 ELSE 0
```

x and y are columns. my problem is, `sum(y)` can be 0 and i get the error dividing by 0 is not possible. How can i catch up this error in the else clause. So that if `y = 0 "ELSE 0"` gets activated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe one more condition ?

```
CASE 
   WHEN sum(y)=0 then 0
   WHEN (1+sum(x)/sum(y)) >=0 and (1+sum(x)/sum(y)) < 0.5 Then 1 
   ELSE 0
END
```

Comment: i choose this solution since it is (for me) the shortest and clearest one. thank u very much!

Comment: I believe that, in some circumstances, this may not be enough to protect you. Trying to find the relevant links now.

Comment: See [Aggregates Don't Follow the Semantics of Case](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/691535/aggregates-dont-follow-the-semantics-of-case), although in that case, the division is within the aggregate, it shows that *some* of the calculation of the second `WHEN` is occurring when the first `WHEN` should evaluate as true.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use expression `NullIf(sum(y), 0)` in place of `sum(y)`:

```
select
    CASE
        WHEN (1+sum(x)/NullIf(sum(y), 0)) >=0
         and (1+sum(x)/NullIf(sum(y), 0)) < 0.5 Then 1
        ELSE 0
    END
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/7a1ec/3) sample

Comment: i dont think it remove divide by zero exception

Comment: [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/7a1ec/3) sample (set it up before you comment, ok, never mind, if it is not helpful, may be I'm missing something)

Comment: @AmitSingh it sure will. I tested it. This is a good solution +1

Comment: @t-clausen.dk, I'm not sure how it will behave if sum is not exactly zero, but something like 1e-17

Comment: @i-one: it is not true that i havent set it up before commenting. i tried: (sum(x) - NULLIF(sum(CASE WHEN day IS NULL THEN y ELSE 0 END)/CAST(sum(CASE WHEN day IS NULL THEN y ELSE 0 END)  as Decimal(18,2)),0)). Still giving me the "dividing by 0" error.

Comment: @ruedi, I mean't another, I mean't that I set my sqlfiddle sample up (link in the comment), before your comment to my ahswer that `NullIf` is not helpful, just decided to post it anyway. Added link to answer.

Comment: @ruedi, as I see, you tried it as `NullIf(sum(...)/sum(...), 0)`, where as `NullIf` should be applied to denominator only as `sum(...)/NullIf(sum(...), 0)`

Answer (score 0):

```
case when
              sum(coalesce(y, 0)) <> 0 
              and (1+sum(x)/sum(coalesce(y, 0))) >= 0 
              and (1+sum(x)/sum(coalesce(y, 0))) < 0.5 then 
   1 
else
   0
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to check if the Denominator is Zero first
If yes then dont calculate the formula return Zero
Else
Calculate the formula

In Code:

```
CASE WHEN (1+sum(x)/sum(y)) >=0 and (1+sum(x)/sum(y)) < 0.5 Then 1
ELSE 0
```

Modify it as:

```
CASE
WHEN SUM(isnull(y,0))=0 then 0
ELSE
  CASE
     WHEN (1+sum(x)/sum(y)) >=0 and (1+sum(x)/sum(y)) < 0.5
     THEN 1
  END
END AS [RESULT]
```